# Update mapping index parameter of existing field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have the mapping

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "location" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to update the `index` parameter of the `location` field to `true`

I am trying

```
PUT /test/_mapping
{
  
    "properties": {
        "location": { 
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": true
        }
    }
  
}
```

and I am getting

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [location] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [location] has different [index] values]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [location] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [location] has different [index] values]"},"status":400}
```

How to update the `index` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What you are trying to achieve is called breaking changes or conflicting changes** and is not possible and same is mentioned in the error message.

Think of what index param does and why its breaking changes, from [index docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html)

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts
> true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are
> not queryable.

Earlier index value was `false` so your existing documents didn't have value indexed and wasn't queryable and now you changing to `true` which doesn't make sense as your earlier documents will not have the indexed value and that's the reason its called breaking changes.

You have to create a new index with new index value and you can use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) for that.

Comment: And use alias to avoid application side changes.

Comment: Here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#update-mapping we can find that update is allowed to supported mapping parameters, and `index` parameter is listed

Comment: @Gibbs thanks for mentioning alias, wanted to add but forgot :D